# Using modules to run all sheets in a workbook - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

For a project that I have been working on, I finally completed the code used to analyze a quarterly schedule, and now I am trying to have my code analyze all four sheets within the workbook (each sheet represents a different quarter).

The error that I am experiencing is "run time error 1004 method range of object _global failed"

I am currently using a module to run the code for all four sheets. My code is as follows:

```
sub scheduleAnalyzer()

Dim ws_count As Integer
Dim I As Integer

ws_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For I = 1 To ws_count 

    'then my code which analyzes the schedule and prints results on a new sheet

Next I

End Sub
```

This is my first time using a module to run code.  The error occurs in the following place:

```
Dim month1 As Range
Dim month2 As Range
Dim month3 As Range
Dim month1_start As String
Dim month1_end As String
Dim month2_start As String
Dim month2_end As String
Dim month3_start As String
Dim month3_end As String  

month1_start = "B6"
monthRow = 6
dayRow = 7

For k = 2 To maxCol
    If Cells(monthRow, k).Interior.color = colorArray(10) And Cells(monthRow, k + 1).Interior.color = colorArray(11) Then
        month1_end = Cells(monthRow, k).Address
        month2_start = Cells(monthRow, k + 1).Address
    ElseIf Cells(monthRow, k).Interior.color = colorArray(11) And Cells(monthRow, k + 1).Interior.color = colorArray(10) Then
        month2_end = Cells(monthRow, k).Address
        month3_start = Cells(monthRow, k + 1).Address
    ElseIf Cells(monthRow, k).Interior.color = colorArray(10) And Cells(monthRow, k + 1).Interior.color = colorArray(9) Then
        month3_end = Cells(monthRow, k).Address
    End If
Next k

month1 = Range(month1_start, month1_end) '<--------------- run-time error 1004 method range of object _global failed
month2 = Range(month2_start, month2_end)
month3 = Range(month3_start, month3_end)
```

I know that this code works when I am just running for one particular sheet.  Is this the best way to go about running it through a whole workbook? If so, how do I go about fixing this error?  I tried using a With statement with "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets()" but I am unable to name a singular ws to put in the parentheses since I want it ran in all four of them.

Comment: Is the code for processing a quarter in a subroutine?  Are you passing the appropriate worksheet to that subroutine as a parameter?  Or is the code for processing a quarter just embedded within your main module (i.e. the second code block in your question is just inserted inside the loop in your first code block)?  (Your problem is almost certainly due to the processing code not knowing which worksheet it is processing, but it's a bit hard to help you fix that without seeing the code which determines which sheet is to be processed.)

Comment: @YowE3K yes, everything is within one `sub scheduleAnalyzer()`.  I believe that part of the problem that is it does not know which sheet (quarter) to run the code through.  Is using a module the best method for having code run through all sheets?

Comment: `month1 = Range(month1_start, month1_end)` should be `Set month1 = Range(month1_start, month1_end)`, but that leads me to wonder how the code works on even a single sheet.

Comment: Personally, I would have the code to process a single worksheet in a subroutine, and I would pass that subroutine a parameter saying which sheet it should work with.  E.g. `Sub ProcessAQuarter(ws As Worksheet)` `With ws` ... `Set month1 = .Range(month1_start, month1_end)` ... `End With` `End Sub` and then call that subroutine four times in the main module.  But that's just my personal preference (to "compartmentalise" code) - it can be done just as easily in the main module.

Comment: Qualify `Range` calls with a worksheet object instance, e.g. `Sheet1.Range`. Ditto with `Cells`; unqualified, these functions implicitly refer to *the active sheet*. Passing them parameters that refer to *other sheets* causes the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you would definitely be getting an error due to not using `Set` to set your `Range` variables, but that would be a "Object variable or With block variable not set" error.

The "method range of object _global failed" error you were getting is probably because `month1_end` had not been set, which may be because your code never sets variable `maxCol` (and thus your `For k =` loop would never have executed), or you may have set `maxCol` in code that isn't posted in your question in which case `month1_end` may not have been set correctly as it wasn't processing the Worksheet you intended.

The following code should, hopefully, get around some of those errors and give you a structure on which you can build your looping:

```
sub scheduleAnalyzer()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim month1 As Range
    Dim month2 As Range
    Dim month3 As Range
    Dim month1_start As String
    Dim month1_end As String
    Dim month2_start As String
    Dim month2_end As String
    Dim month3_start As String
    Dim month3_end As String  
    'monthRow is not defined in original code
    Dim monthRow As Long
    'dayRow is not defined in original code
    Dim dayRow As Long
    'k is not defined in original code
    Dim k As Long
    'maxCol isn't defined or assigned a value in original code
    Dim maxCol As Long
    maxCol = 36 ' <-- purely random number - please assign it how you were assigning it when code was working

    For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        With ws

            month1_start = "B6"
            monthRow = 6
            dayRow = 7

            For k = 2 To maxCol
                If .Cells(monthRow, k).Interior.color = colorArray(10) And .Cells(monthRow, k + 1).Interior.color = colorArray(11) Then
                    month1_end = .Cells(monthRow, k).Address
                    month2_start = .Cells(monthRow, k + 1).Address
                ElseIf .Cells(monthRow, k).Interior.color = colorArray(11) And .Cells(monthRow, k + 1).Interior.color = colorArray(10) Then
                    month2_end = .Cells(monthRow, k).Address
                    month3_start = .Cells(monthRow, k + 1).Address
                ElseIf .Cells(monthRow, k).Interior.color = colorArray(10) And .Cells(monthRow, k + 1).Interior.color = colorArray(9) Then
                    month3_end = .Cells(monthRow, k).Address
                End If
            Next k

            Set month1 = .Range(month1_start, month1_end)
            Set month2 = .Range(month2_start, month2_end)
            Set month3 = .Range(month3_start, month3_end)

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

---

**EDIT** following comments:

A minimalist approach to enable an existing Sub called scheduleAnalyzer (*which is assumed to be currently working for a single, active, worksheet*) to process every worksheet in the workbook would be:

```
Sub RunAllScheduleAnalyzer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws in Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        scheduleAnalyzer
    Next
End Sub
```

I do not recommend this as anything other than a short-term workaround - using `Activate` (and `Select`) to determine which cells will be processed by a VBA application is something to be avoided if at all possible, as it leads to too many "but this code **normally** works !?!?" type of problems.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  My code is approx. 600 lines (and it works), so that would be a lot of editing.  Lets step back for a min to better view the problem.  I have my working code in a sheet module, Sheet1 (OCT-DEC).  I need it to run on the next three sheets as well.  Is there a way I can simply put something along the lines of `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OCT-DEC")
 scheduleAnalyzer()` and then repeat that and changing the name of the worksheet?

Comment: I know my overall problem is simple, I just do not understand the hierarchy of modules in VBA. Unfortunately, resources for learning VBA are not as bountiful as those for Python or anything else really.

Comment: @JonSnow - I have edited my answer to show a simple way that you can get a Sub that currently processes a single sheet successfully to process all worksheets.